# Can I wrap a class around an array element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of checkboxes that are used for filtering called `$('.filters input')`.

I add these filters to an array:

```
  $('.filters input').each(function (counter, element) {
    if (element.checked) {
      $selectedFilters.push({
        name: element.name,
        class: element.value,
      });
    }
  })
```

In the next section I join the elements:

```
 if ($selectedFilters.length > 0) {
    $filters = $selectedFilters.map(function (elem) {
      return elem.class;
    }).join(', ');

    let $names = $selectedFilters.map(function (elem) {
      return elem.name;
    }).join(' ');
```

Then I output this text:

```
$('.filter-box__applied-filters').html(`<div class="btn btn-primary">${$names}</div>`);
```

But this adds each array item within the same div, how would I make it so each item appears in a new div?

Comment: Did you try `appendChild()` instead of `html`?

Comment: it will be better if you provide a live example

Answer (score 0):

Since $names is an array you have to loop over $names and append a new child to the $('.filter-box__applied-filters') element to create each filter separately in

```
$names.each(function(filterName){
   $('.filter-box__applied-filters').append(`<div class="btn btn-primary">`+filterName+`</div>`);
})
```

[jquery documentation for .each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)